# How to use split large dataset in train/test set but also use pandas batchsize itererations for updating

Tags: loops, testing, dask, chunks

I am updating my parameters every iteration with a batch from a very large file. But before I do this I want to split the entire large dataset in a test and a train set. And with crossvalidation I want to do the same.

I have tried to use dask to split the entire set and then transform a partion to pandas to use batches for updating my algorithm.

#### the dask part (which I if possible would rather not use):

```
dict_bag=dff.read_csv("gdrive/My Drive/train_triplets.txt",  blocksize=int(1e9),sep='\s+',header=None)
df_train, df_test = df_bag.random_split([2/3, 1/3], random_state=0)
df_batch=df_train.loc[1:1000].compute()
```

#### the pandas part:

```
df_chunk = pd.read_csv("gdrive/My Drive/train_triplets.txt", chunksize=6000000,sep='\s+',header=None)
for chunk in df_chunk:

####    here I have my algorithm
```

I expect that it is possible to have a pandas function to create a pd file with chunksizes from a url as I already have but then split in a train and a test set. So that I can iterate in batches over the large train and test set individually. And so that I can also split the trainset for me to perform crossvalidation.

Edit: My Dataframe is a textfilereader, how do I get a train and test set from this and/or can I do crossvalidation

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the [dask.dataframe.random_split](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.random_split) method.

50/50 split

```
>>> a, b = df.random_split([0.5, 0.5])
```

80/10/10 split, for example for train/test/validation

```
>>> a, b, c = df.random_split([0.8, 0.1, 0.1], random_state=123)
```

Comment: Yes. And how will I then use batches as i used with pd.csv_open(batchsize=100.000) ? So I want my dask trainingset back to a textfilereader type that you get from that code.